# recorrer array con foreach php poo

Tags: php, poo, foreach

estoy tratando de recorrer un array con php en POO y MVC el problema es que no logro hacerlo.

Este es el action.class.php:

```
            $devolucion = getXMLValue($var1, "identificador");
        $devolucion2 = getXMLValue($var2, "Fecha_Alta");
        $devolucion3 = getXMLValue($var3, "codigo_movimiento");
        $devolucion4 = getXMLValue($var4, "codigo_denuncia");
        $devolucion5 = getXMLValue($var5, "user_id");
        $devolucion6 = getXMLValue($var6, "lnv_id");

        $this->mi_array = array(devolucion2, $devolucion3, $devolucion4, $devolucion5, $devolucion6);
```

Esta es la vista:

```
 <?php foreach($mi_array as $datosArray): ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $datosArray->devolucion2;?></td>
                                    <!-- <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td> -->
                                </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Necesito mostrar los datos del array en un foreach al cual lo he generado en la vista dentro de este va a una tabla para mostrar los resultados.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? Veo que aquí te falta la `$` antes de `devolucion2`:  **`array(devolucion2, $devolucion3, ...)`** y en el `foreach`, si estás en el contexto del objeto, tienes que usar también `$this`  para referirte a `$mi_array`. En cualquier caso, haz un `var_dump` del objeto que intentas leer para ver lo que tiene y cómo está estructurado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En action.class.php tendrías que hacer:

```
$devolucion = getXMLValue($var1, "identificador");
    $devolucion2 = getXMLValue($var2, "Fecha_Alta");
    $devolucion3 = getXMLValue($var3, "codigo_movimiento");
    $devolucion4 = getXMLValue($var4, "codigo_denuncia");
    $devolucion5 = getXMLValue($var5, "user_id");
    $devolucion6 = getXMLValue($var6, "lnv_id");

    $this->mi_array = ["devolucion2"=>$devolucion2, "devolucion3"=>$devolucion3, "devolucion4"=>$devolucion4, "devolucion5"=>$devolucion5, "devolucion6"=>$devolucion6];
```

Y en tu Html hacer:

```
<tr>
                                <td><?php echo $datosArray['devolucion2']?></td>
                                <!-- <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td> -->
                            </tr>
```